# Sublime color syntax for Ruby variables vs keywords

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

Is there a way for Sublime Text 2 to display different colors for Ruby "variables" vs "keywords"? The image below is an example of Ruby code with the default Monokai color scheme. I was hoping I could having the variables (list, x) be a different color than the keywords (each, print).

Currently, they're all tied to `<key>foreground</key>`. I did try changing the `variable` color, but that only changed for the `|x|`.

[image: Example of Ruby color syntax]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a way to do this with the default Ruby syntax that ships with Sublime. `list`, `each`, `print`, and `x` are all scoped as `source.ruby`, meaning they don't have a specific scope that can be targeted by a color scheme. On the other hand, `end` is scoped `keyword.control.ruby`, and `do` is `keyword.control.start-block.ruby` (in addition to the base `source.ruby` scope that applies to all elements), so if you have a rule in your color scheme for `keyword` or `keyword.control`, they can be colored differently. `|x|` is `punctuation.separator.variable.ruby` for the pipes `|`, and `variable.other.block.ruby` for `x`, so those can be adjusted per your preferences.

Essentially, an item can only be colored if it has a distinct scope, and your color scheme contains a rule for that scope (or a more generalized version of it, but not a more specific version of it). Ruby is especially challenging as compared to Python, for example, as while Python methods always have parentheses at the end (`string_var.replace()`, for example) and regexes can be written to highlight anything between the dot `.` and the parens as a function call, Ruby does not follow this paradigm, so the syntax highlighting definition (found in the various `.tmLanguage` files) cannot distinguish between a method call and a simple attribute, and so cannot highlight them differentially. This is why `list.each` in your program is only `source.ruby`, and `each` is not highlighted as a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. I had the same issue. Hopefully this can be fixed one day.